# Интерфейс создания таблицы как в MS Word

Tags: jquery, ui, ms-word

Как реализовать интерфейс создания таблицы как в Microsoft Word c помощью jQuery?

Не получается. Подскажите, как сделать? 
[Вот пример](http://jsfiddle.net/Alex_K88/dGEud/)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#toogle").hide();
    $(".gradient").click(function () {
        $("#toogle").slideToggle(150);
    });

    var w = 9,
        h = 8;
    var row, col;
    var i;
    for (i = 2; i <= w * h; i++) {
        row = Math.ceil(i / w);
        col = Math.round(i - (row - 1) * (w));
        $('.box_one ul').append("<li class='item' row=" + row + "  col=" + col + ">" + "</li>");
        console.log(col);
    }

    function each_item(item) {
        var row0, col0;
        $(item).each(function () {
            row0 = $(this).attr('row');
            col0 = $(this).attr('col');
        });
        return {
            row0: row0,
            col0: col0
        };
    }

    function show_white(row, col) {
        $('.item').each(function (ind) {
            if (each_item(this).row0 <= row && each_item(this).col0 <= col) {
                $(this).addClass("item_white");
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass("item_white");
            }
        });

    }

    $(".item").mouseover(function () {
        $(this).addClass("item_white");
        row = $(this).attr('row');

        col = $(this).attr('col');
        //console.log(col);
        show_white(row, col);

        append_title(col);
    });
    //console.log(col);
    function append_title(title) {
        var parse_col = parseFloat(title);
        //console.log(parse_col);
        $(parse_col).each(function (index, element) {
            console.log(element);
            if (this <= element) {
                console.log("cil" + element);
                $(".box_two ul").append("<li class='item' >" + index + "</li>");
            } else if (this > element) {
                var child = $(".box_two ul").children();
                console.log(child);
                //$(".box_two ul li").remove();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}
body {
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(/image/squairy_light_@2X.png);
}
.content_html {
    width: 850px;
    height: 100%;
    /*border:1px solid #2A0000;*/
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.gradient {
    filter: none;
}
.chair {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position:fixed;
    top:-10px;
    width:850px;
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    -webkit-box-shadow;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    height:10px;
}
h4 {
    border:1px solid #2A0000;
    font-family:'Open Sans', serif;
    font-size:16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    margin: -22px auto;
    background: #d6f9ff;
    /* Old browsers */
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;
    base64, PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiA/Pgo8c3ZnIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDEgMSIgcHJlc2VydmVBc3BlY3RSYXRpbz0ibm9uZSI+CiAgPGxpbmVhckdyYWRpZW50IGlkPSJncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkIiBncmFkaWVudFVuaXRzPSJ1c2VyU3BhY2VPblVzZSIgeDE9IjAlIiB5MT0iMCUiIHgyPSIxMDAlIiB5Mj0iMTAwJSI+CiAgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjAlIiBzdG9wLWNvbG9yPSIjZDZmOWZmIiBzdG9wLW9wYWNpdHk9IjEiLz4KICAgIDxzdG9wIG9mZnNldD0iMTAwJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iIzllZThmYSIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIxIi8+CiAgPC9saW5lYXJHcmFkaWVudD4KICA8cmVjdCB4PSIwIiB5PSIwIiB3aWR0aD0iMSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxIiBmaWxsPSJ1cmwoI2dyYWQtdWNnZy1nZW5lcmF0ZWQpIiAvPgo8L3N2Zz4=);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, #d6f9ff 0%, #9ee8fa 100%);
    /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%, #d6f9ff), color-stop(100%, #9ee8fa));
    /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, #d6f9ff 0%, #9ee8fa 100%);
    /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, #d6f9ff 0%, #9ee8fa 100%);
    /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg, #d6f9ff 0%, #9ee8fa 100%);
    /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, #d6f9ff 0%, #9ee8fa 100%);
    /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#d6f9ff', endColorstr='#9ee8fa', GradientType=1);
    /* IE6-8 fallback on horizontal gradient */
    border-radius:8px 8px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius:8px 8px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius:8px 8px 0 0;
}
aside, #toogle {
    width: auto;
    background: #d6f9ff;
    /* Old browsers */
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;
    base64, 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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, #d6f9ff 0%, #9ee8fa 100%);
    /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%, #d6f9ff), color-stop(100%, #9ee8fa));
    /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, #d6f9ff 0%, #9ee8fa 100%);
    /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, #d6f9ff 0%, #9ee8fa 100%);
    /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg, #d6f9ff 0%, #9ee8fa 100%);
    /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, #d6f9ff 0%, #9ee8fa 100%);
    /* W3C */
}
#toogle {
    border:1px solid red;
    height: 400px;
    background: #d6f9ff;
    /* Old browsers */
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;
    base64, 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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, #d6f9ff 0%, #9ee8fa 100%);
    /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%, #d6f9ff), color-stop(100%, #9ee8fa));
    /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, #d6f9ff 0%, #9ee8fa 100%);
    /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, #d6f9ff 0%, #9ee8fa 100%);
    /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg, #d6f9ff 0%, #9ee8fa 100%);
    /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, #d6f9ff 0%, #9ee8fa 100%);
    /* W3C */
}
.box_one, .box_two {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
    display: block;
    height: 290px;
    width: 320px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    background: #93cede;
    /* Old browsers */
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;
    base64, 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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, #93cede 0%, #75bdd1 41%, #49a5bf 100%);
    /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%, #93cede), color-stop(41%, #75bdd1), color-stop(100%, #49a5bf));
    /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, #93cede 0%, #75bdd1 41%, #49a5bf 100%);
    /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, #93cede 0%, #75bdd1 41%, #49a5bf 100%);
    /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg, #93cede 0%, #75bdd1 41%, #49a5bf 100%);
    /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, #93cede 0%, #75bdd1 41%, #49a5bf 100%);
    /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#93cede', endColorstr='#49a5bf', GradientType=1);
    /* IE6-8 fallback on horizontal gradient */
}
.item {
    display: block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background: red;
    margin: 2px;
    float:left;
    list-style:none
}
.item_white {
    display: block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background: white;
    margin: 2px;
    float:left;
    list-style:none
}
aside {
    height: 50px;
}
.content_table {
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    border:1px solid #2A0000;
    width: auto;
}
.content_table aside {
    background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <header></header>
    <div class="content_html">
        <div class="chair"></div>
        <section>
            <aside id="toogle">
                <nav class="box_one">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="item" row="1" col="1">1</li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <nav class="box_two"></nav>
            </aside>
        </section>
        <section>
            <aside>
                <nav></nav>
            </aside>
             <h4 class="gradient">Create Table</h4>

        </section>
        <section class="content_table">
            <aside>
                <nav></nav>
            </aside>
        </section>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: и что этот пример делает осмысленного кроме показывания бессмысленных alert ?

Comment: проверяет наличие атрибута data-step. Не обращаете внимание на это alert так я проверяю наличие записанных значений.. Здесь нужен новый подход решения я то я совсем запутался

Comment: вы как нибудь всё-таки опишите чего именно хотите.

Comment: при наведении на ячейки должна сформироваться таблица и выделенные ячейки которые окрашиваются в белый цвет определяют количество столбцов. Но у меня выделяются в белый цвет все ячейки.А я хочу что бы у меня выделились например 3 столбца и 3 строки. Вы же знаете как MS office вставлять таблицу.

Comment: нет не знаю не пользуюсь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/8BfHp/2/

не стал сильно вдаваться в ваш пример.
По идее чтобы динамически расширять поле-таблицу нужно менять ширину ul при наведении на '.item' (т.е. когда строка выбранного .item равна максимальному числу строк, то мы увеличиваем число строк и расширяем элемент ul таким образом, чтобы в строку входил на 1 ячейку больше.)

Вставить таблицу можете уже куда угодно - главное (число row и  column ) у вас есть.

Answer (score 1):

Зачем нужны списки? Таблицы вполне достаточно. Немного уличной магии и... [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/ivanovsuper/YbECK/).